# Lottery draw has to many rights each time

Tags: c#

What is the error in my code? It counts the correct numbers wrong.
Input is 7 numbers in an array
Then we have how many random draws it shall be
We also have an array with the random numbers that are correct each time

```
private void CheckLotto()
    {

        Array.Sort(myLotto);
        Array.Sort(SelectedNumbers);
        sevenRatt = 0;
        sixRatt = 0;
        fiveRatt = 0;

        //How many times should we have a draw?
        for (int k = 0; k < howMany; k++)
        {
                int match = 0;

                //Got throw selctedNumbers array
                for (int i = 0; i < SelectedNumbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Go throw mylotto array
                    for (int j = 0; j < myLotto.Length; j++)
                    {
                        //Are thye same?
                        if (SelectedNumbers[i] == myLotto[j])
                        {
                            Console.Write("{0}  ", SelectedNumbers[i]);
                            match++;
                        }//if

                        switch(match)
                        {
                            case 5:
                                fiveRatt++;
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                sixRatt++;
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                sevenRatt++;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                           }// switch

                    }//for
                }//for
            }//try
          
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the switch is in the wrong spot -- it is in the inner loop (which does a count how many correct numbers you got).  You need it to be outside that loop and in the loop (which loops over how many to test).

```
private void CheckLotto()
{

    Array.Sort(myLotto);
    Array.Sort(SelectedNumbers);
    sevenRatt = 0;
    sixRatt = 0;
    fiveRatt = 0;

    //How many times should we have a draw?
    for (int k = 0; k < howMany; k++)
    {
            int match = 0;

            //Got throw selctedNumbers array
            for (int i = 0; i < SelectedNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                //Go throw mylotto array
                for (int j = 0; j < myLotto.Length; j++)
                {
                    //Are thye same?
                    if (SelectedNumbers[i] == myLotto[j])
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0}  ", SelectedNumbers[i]);
                        match++;
                    }//if

                }//for
            }//for
            
            switch(match)
            {
               case 5:
                  fiveRatt++;
                  break;
               case 6:
                  sixRatt++;
                  break;
               case 7:
                  sevenRatt++;
                  break;
            }// switch

   } // for main        
    
}
```